# How to create a rule to compare an order total with a custom field in a content type?

Tags: rules, commerce

I have multiple restaurants with each another value for minimum order price, this is a custom price field in the content type "Restaurants".

I would need to make a rule where the total order amount is compared to this custom price field. If the total from the order is lower, it should redirect and throw a message.

The problem here is that I don't know what entities to use to get access to the custom price field named "field_leveringsprijs".

The event is on payment selection or checkout completion. The actions would be a page redirect and a message which isn't hard to do. I'm just stuck with the conditions 'Entity has field' and 'Data comparison'.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your `field_leveringsprijs` (with "levering" = delivery, and "prijs" = price) corresponds to your *minimum order price* of your Restaurants content type.

If such field is not available as a token to use it in a Rules Condition, then the typical approach/solution is to use the Rules *Action* (not Rules Condition ...) "***Fetch entity by id***". So if you do have the id of the Retaurant available, just fetch the Restaurant (=some node of content type Restaurants). That will make all its fields, such as your `field_leveringsprijs` field, available for *subsequent* processing.

***But***, such *Fetch entity by id* is a Rules Action, so that's like you're too late to use the result of that Rules Action within the typical Rules Conditions (as you are trying to do in the data comparison shown in your question). The way to get around that, is to use either of following approaches:

- Use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, which basically allows you to add a Rules Condition as part of the Rules Actions you want to perform. So using this module/technique, you'd specify something equivalent to "if order total is below `field_leveringsprijs`". And then add the actual Rules Actions you want to perform in that case (= perform a redirect, and show some message).
- Create a Rules Component in which you execute (as Rules Actions) those actions such as that redirect and display a message). But which also includes a Rules Condition equivalent to "if order total is below `field_leveringsprijs`". **And** (this is crucial!) make sure to pass a "parameter" to this Rules Component, which will reprezent your `field_leveringsprijs` (with same data type). After you QA-tested your Rules Component, go back to your original Rule, and simply execute that Rules Component, by passing the appropriate value of the Rules Component parameter, using ... indeed ... your `field_leveringsprijs` (which you got via that "Fetch entity by id", remember?).